# JS: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter is not of type 'Element' in making responsive careusol

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Hey I make a responsive carousel using js in react but when I run this code I got an error
In short: I am trying to understand why I am getting this TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element' The error appears while I was running my code **

**js code**

```
const track = document.querySelector('.track');
let initialPosition = null;
let moving= false;
let transform=0;

const gestureStart = (e) =>{
    initialPosition  = e.pageX;
    moving = true;
    const transformMatrix = window.getComputedStyle(track).getPropertyValue('transform');
    console.log(transformMatrix)
    if(transformMatrix !== "none")
    transform = parseInt(transformMatrix.split(',')[4].trim())
}

 const getureMove = (e) =>{
    if(moving){
        const currentPosition = e.pageX;
        const diff = currentPosition - initialPosition;
        track.style.transform= `translateX(${transform + diff}px)`
    }
 }

 const  gestureEnd = (e) =>{
    moving =false;
 }

if(window.PointerEvent){
    window.addEventListener('pointerdown',gestureStart);
    window.addEventListener('pointermove',getureMove);
    window.addEventListener('pointerup',gestureEnd);
}
else{
    window.addEventListener('touchdown',gestureStart);
    window.addEventListener('touchmove',getureMove);
    window.addEventListener('touchup',gestureEnd);
    window.addEventListener('mousedown',gestureStart);
    window.addEventListener('mousemove',getureMove);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup',gestureEnd);
}
```

**html code**

```
return (
    <div className="container">
        <div className="carousel">
            <div className="track">
                <div className="cards"></div>
                <div className="cards"></div>
                <div className="cards"></div>
                <div className="cards"></div>
                <div className="cards"></div>
                <div className="cards"></div>
                <div className="cards"></div>
                <div className="cards"></div>
                <div className="cards"></div>
                <div className="cards"></div>
                <div className="cards"></div>
                <div className="cards"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is running while the DOM is not ready yet.

When the DOM is ready, the selector returns the object.

You can use this code:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
//Your JS code.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I got this error when I switched my code from

```
jQuery(function($){ some code });
```

to

```
(function() { some code });
```

This was fixed when I switch back.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).